# Prove/Disprove $f(x)$ is not differentiable at any point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> x^2& \text{if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$,}\\
> -x^2&  \text{if $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$.}
> \end{cases}$$
>   Prove/Disprove: $f(x)$ is not differentiable at any point.

It seems that the function has a removable discontinuity as $$\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}^+}-x^2=-2=\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}^-}-x^2=\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}^-}f(x)$$
but $$f(\sqrt{2})=(\sqrt{2})^2=2$$

So it is not differentiable at $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$ but because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then it is not differentiable at any point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, you should check the continuity at the points where $x^2=-x^2$, i.e. $x=0$. As regards the differentiability at $x=0$, we need to verify whether the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\pm x^2-0}{x}.$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. The above density property implies that there is a sequence $(x_k)_k$ of rational numbers which tends to $\sqrt{2}$ and $f(x_k)=x_k^2\to (\sqrt{2})^2=2$ on the other hand $f(\sqrt{2})=-(\sqrt{2})^2=-2$ because $\sqrt{2}\not \in \mathbb{Q}$. It follows that $f$ is not even continuous (and hence certainly not differentiable) at $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: We saw that the function is not continuous for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ isn't it enough to show that the claim is true?

Comment: Have you checked continuity/differentiability at $x=0$?

Comment: Yes, it is $0$, so it differentiable for $x=0$ so it is not true, Thanks!